# spoj ACPC10D -Why i am getting the wrong answer?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Here's my code .It is passing the testcase given in the problem statement.
  Link for problem :http://www.spoj.com/problems/ACPC10D/ 
   tri[i][j] stores the min value to reach at index (i,j) from  tri[0][1].

```
 //trigraphs-dp
#include<iostream>
#include<limits.h>
using namespace std;
int tri[1000000][3];
int min(int a,int b)
{
if(a<=b)
return a;

else
return b;
}

int main()
{
int n,t=1;
while(cin>>n)
{

    if(n==0)
    break;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    cin>>tri[i][j];

    tri[0][0]=INT_MAX;

    tri[0][2]=tri[0][1]+tri[0][2];
    //cout<<tri[0][2];

    int a,b,c,d;
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        a=tri[i-1][j];
        b=(j==2)?INT_MAX:tri[i-1][j+1];
        c=(j==0)?INT_MAX:tri[i-1][j-1];
        d=(j==0)?INT_MAX:tri[i][j-1];

        tri[i][j]+=min(min(a,b),min(c,d));
   }

   cout<<t<<". "<<tri[n-1][1]<<"\n";

    }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about make some test-output every time the values are updated. The Problem is small enough to detect in which step something went wrong by looking at all the changes.

Comment: Please comment your code and have its format reflect its structure.

Answer (score 0):

1- You forgot to increment **t** in the end of the loop

2- Define **tri** as **long long** type because of possible overflow when you add up numbers.